# JSONObject using memory address for array in android 4.3, content of array in other versions

Tags: android, gson

I am using gson 2.2.4.

The code in question:

```
int[] byte_message = new int[message.getBytes("UTF8").length];
for (int i = 0; i < message.getBytes("UTF8").length; i++) {
    byte_message[i] = message.getBytes("UTF8")[i] & 0xff;
}
result.put("message", byte_message);
JSONObject json_obj = new JSONObject(result);
String json = json_obj.toString();
```

In Android version of 4.3, the `json` variable contains:

```
{"message":"[I@4135f3b0"}
```

In other versions for the same exact code, the `json` variable contains:

```
{"message":[66,106]}
```

Can anyone explain this discrepancy?

Comment: What about "UTF-8" instead of "UTF8" ?

Comment: that didn't change anything.

Comment: Did you try with the latest version of Gson (3.2.1)?